# How should I work with day-since-epoch values before C++20 is approved?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono, days

I'm writing some code which uses days-since-some-epoch and year-month-day representations of dates, independently. **edit:** I should also mention that the years may theoretically be negative, and [year 0 may or may not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero).

Now, C++20 will introduce an [`std::year_month_day` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day), which should be quite useful, both in itself and in interaction with my classes. For now, though, should I even use `std::chrono` for my dates at all, or is it too useless if I only ever add up and subtract day-resolution dates?

Answer (score 5):

The extensions to `<chrono>` have been completely accepted. It looks to me that if you get a hold of a library containing them, it should not break when upgrading to C++20.

That said, the [proposal](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/d0355r7.html) refers to a [working implementation](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) by the author of that proposal. If it really does what you want, I suggest you use that as external library.

Important to note is that library should be able to handle all special cases you can think of related to time. Time zones, February 29 ...
Just so you don't have to consider them, I'd recommend using this class over an own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I've upvoted JVApen's answer and encourage you to accept that as the best answer.  However I wanted to add just a little more information that might be helpful to you.

The C++20 proposal is set up to interoperate with multiple user-written calendars.  Indeed, the [working implementation](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that JVApen refers to actually implements several example user-written calendars.  The key to having your custom calendar class interoperate with the `std::chrono` system is to have it do just one thing:

1. Implicitly convert to and from `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>>`.

The above awful-looking type has a more convenient name in C++20 which is just a `typedef` to the above type: `sys_days`.  This is just a `time_point` using `system_clock` with a precision of `days`.  Under the hood, this type holds nothing more than a count of days since (or before) 1970-01-01.

If your calendrical type can convert to and from this `std::chrono` type (which exists in C++11/14/17 except for the `typedef`), then you can use `std::chrono` to very efficiently do day-oriented arithmetic since it will literally just be adding/subtracting to an `int` under the hood.

And once you have this day-precision `time_point`, `chrono` makes it very easy to add "time of day" to it just by adding hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, whatever to it, for example:

```
system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days{2018y/June/3} + 14h + 15min + 36s + 123ms;
```

(sub in your calendrical system for `2018y/June/3`)

Comment: It's not awful-looking, although it could use a `seconds_in_a_day` constant, or decomposition into 60*60*24. Also, on another note, the conversion may be costly, so I was kind of hoping for something that's `chrono`-friendly but supports specifying a different epoch and Gregorian vs ISO years (i.e. with/without year 0).

Comment: C++20 has a new `duration` type alias called `days`.  This is where that constant lives.  There's also a templated type alias:   `template <class Duration>
    using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>;`, so `sys_days` is also the same type as `sys_time<days>`.

Comment: Here are highly efficient public domain calendrical algorithms.  You can use these to implement the conversions to/from `sys_days`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Comment: `tai_clock` (in the C++20 draft) is a good example of a clock system that has an epoch shift.  It counts time since 1958-01-01 and has conversions to/from UTC.  This is how it is implemented: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/tz.h#L1998

Comment: I'm sure they're efficient (I saw the presentation), but not as efficient as _not_ doing any conversion and just wrapping / reinterpreting existing data...

Comment: One can construct a `sys_days` from an integral type like this: `sys_days today{days{17685}};`  This involves no arithmetic and simply stores `17685` into the `chrono::time_point`.

Comment: Well, yes, but that works with the default epoch and year-zero choice. But both you and JVApen's answers got their +1's from me.

Comment: One can use "negate and increment" to convert between BC and the ISO system.  I've updated my docs to clarify use of the ISO/year{0} system.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: This begs for defect report :P  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: I see the wink but am unsure of the joke.  Just fyi, the C++20 draft supports leap seconds under `std::chrono::utc_clock/utc_time`.  This measure incorporates the leap seconds added since 1970.  It obviously needs an underlying database that can only see into the future about 6 months.  But with that constraint, subtraction across leap-second-boundaries will get the correct number of physical seconds.